# German Ö in Ukrainian geographical names

Tags: фонетика, іншомовні-слова

In official Ukrainian language German geographical names containing letter **Ö** are transliterated in  a way that strongly change the pronunciation.

*Köln* → *Кельн*  [keln] (instead of logical *Кьольн*)

*Göttingen* → *Геттінген* [getingen] (instead of logical *Гьоттінген*)

What is the reason of such strange transliteration and are there other examples when transliteration does not follow the pronunciation of the original language?

Answer (score 3):

#### First reason

**The Spelling** of 2019 year [for example], [quote](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=130):

> #### § 132. Букви та буквосполучення ö, ø, eu, ое
>
> Голосні, яким на письмі відповідають букви й буквосполучення **ö**, **ø**, **ое**, **eu**, у **німецькій**, данській, іспанській, норвезькій, турецькій, французькій, шведській та деяких інших мовах, і фонетично подібні до них голосні передаємо українською буквою **е**: *Ге́те*, *Бʼєрнсон*, *Ке́льн*, *Пасте́р*, *Рентге́н*, *Ма́льме*, *Вільне́в*, *Е́нчепінг*, а після звука [**j**] буквою **є**: *Рішельє́*, *Бʼє́рнсон*.

*Short:* **ö** → **е** or **є** /je/ if a sound of [**j**] is before.

#### Second reason

They are **the closest sounds**.

- German **ö** usually represents sounds [**ø**] or [**œ**] <sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96)</sup>, for example we would have [kœln] <sup>[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cologne)</sup> and [ˈɡœtɪŋən] <sup>[[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6ttingen)</sup>.
- Ukrainian does not have the sounds, but has an **e** which represent usualy [**e**] or [**ɛ**]. For compare, mentioned here **о** represent [**ɔ**] or [**o**] <sup>[[4]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Ukrainian)</sup>. So, not that strongly.

```
            Front               Central                 Back
Close        i • y –––––––––––– ɨ • ʉ  ––––––––––––––  ɯ • u
                \                  \                     |
Near-close       \     ɪ • ʏ        \            • ʊ     |
                  \  ↓               \  ↓                |
Close-mid      → e • ø –––––––––––– ɘ • ɵ –––––––––––– ɤ • o ←
                    \                  \                 |
Mid                  • ø̞                ə                • o̞
                      \  ↓               \               |
Open-mid           → ɛ • œ –––––––––––– ɜ • ɞ –––––––– ʌ • ɔ ←
                        \                  \             |
Near-open              æ •                  ɐ            |
                          \                  \           |
Open                     a • ɶ –––––––––––– ä • –––––– ɑ • ɒ

Legend:
– unrounded • rounded
– «arrows» show about sounds which mentioned here.
IPA vowels map
```

Another notices:

- It is not normal for Ukrainian to have soft **г** /h/ and **k** /k/. This situation is same for German, or South Slavic languages which also write with **е** as [Гетинген](https://sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD) /getingen/ or [Келн](https://sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BD) /keln/.
- It is Muscovian style for German sounds as **ё** /jo/ which in free-style writing usually writed just as **e**. But Muscovian has different phonology, especial for vowels, for this case **ë** also can be as [**ɵ**] <sup>[[5]](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)</sup> which rounded and close enough, and their **к** with **г** /g/ can be soft.

Comment: Isn't ьо the right sound?

Comment: @P.Vowk What do you mean? For Ukrainian itʼs just _previous half-soft consonant + o_. As I writed, not every consonants can be soft (for example, for Muscovian itʼs famous _ц_, hovewer they can sometimes write as soft, because their language mostly based on transliteration) and _e_ is closer to _ö_ then _o_.